# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' Have tried everything and nothing worked

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, selenium-webdriver, pip

[enter image description here][1]I get the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' error and cant seem to solve it no matter what. ive tried everything related to pip3 and python and nothing seems to work. everything looks normal to me. It doesnt look like i can import anything as i get the same error for other modules. It was all working until recently then randomly i just started getting this error. i tried making a new user on my macbook and trying that way, i managed to get the script to open a site and it managed to do that on a new user but anything more than that would result in chrome closing. Another thing ive noticed is that i cant locate the usr/local/bin file, when run chflags nohidden ~/usr/local/bin it says no such file or directory. i do remember installing chrome webdriver in the bin file so i dont know whats going on there. ive added some useful images, Please please any help would be much appreciated.[image]
[image]

(response to John Gordans comment) thanks so much for your response, ive attached the outputs.
[image: show undetected chromedriver and print sys path]

Comment: It looks like you have two (or more) different installations of python on your computer.  Show us the output of this command `pip3 show undetected-chromedriver`, especially the `Location` output, and also show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Comment: And please include those outputs as part of the question, not as a comment.

Comment: just updated now

Comment: Well, that's the problem.  You're using Python 3.9 to run code, but `pip3` is installing packages for Python 3.11.

Comment: You need to decide which version you want to use, and then make sure all your tools agree on that version.

Comment: id like to use 3.11, im very new to python how would i go about making sure all my tools agree on that? also what about the whole usr/local/bin thing? is it not related? thanks in advance

Comment: How, exactly, do you run the code?  Do you use an IDE such as PyCharm or VS Code?  Or do you use some other way?

Comment: i just do it through sublime and command B

Comment: What is "command B"?  Is that some action within Sublime?

Comment: its a just a shortcut i believe its a shell alias, im not exactly sure but to set it up i just followed a tutorial where i created a new build system and pasted in some code. the output of which python 3 is in the first image at the bottom  lines of the terminal window

Comment: Okay, so I think you need to change/update the build system in Sublime to use `python3` as the command, instead of `python`.

Comment: i think that should work, when i try running directly through terminal the code works

Answer (score 0):

John Gordan's solution:

"Okay, so I think you need to change/update the build system in Sublime to use python3 as the command, instead of python."